# cp command in macOS doesn't recognise "-t" flag

Tags: linux, bash, macos, makefile

I'm migrating a project from linux to macOS.

in the makefile I used `cp -t source/folder/ file1 file2 file3` to copy multiple files into a folder.

but when I run this makefile in macOS, it gives me the following error:

```
cp -v -t ~/Users/admin/Dev/project/export/folder/results/ Output1.txt Output2.txt file1.txt filet2.txt code1.cpp code2.cpp
cp: illegal option -- t
```

is there an equivalent command for the same functionality in macOS?

Comment: You could install the [gnu utilities](https://ryanparman.com/posts/2019/using-gnu-command-line-tools-in-macos-instead-of-freebsd-tools/)  on MacOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp Output1.txt Output2.txt file1.txt filet2.txt code1.cpp code2.cpp ~/Users/admin/Dev/project/export/folder/results/` ?

Stupid GNU... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation here: https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html

The MacOS version of `cp` does not have `-t`

Comment: Yes it works without the -t like hd1's answer